# GWT - How to manage HTML got from server

Tags: gwt

I'm creating a web user interface with GWT, that must "cover" the UI of an existing web platform (I have no control to the original UI, but I can work on the same server). So, I make the request, I got the HTML from the old UI, than I need to parse the HTML and select the informations I need to present in my UI. What is the best way to do this last step (parsing and extracting informations from HTML)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do the parsing of the HTML on the GWT client.

You need to set up a proxy servlet. The proxy servlet accesses the legacy (old) HTML application on behalf of the GWT client. Proxy also acts as main servlet for GWT client.

Proces flow

1. Application context serves the GWT application to the browser.
2. Application context readies a service listener /legacy.
3. GWT app running on browser readies widgets.
4. GWT app sends requests for data to /legacy/Patient/476854.
5. Proxy/Service servlet responds to request /legacy/Patient/476854
6. Proxy/Service servlet decides where to get the data.
7. Proxy/Service servlet decides that most data comes from legacy Patient info app //hello:8888//SantaClaus?patient=476854.
8. Proxy/Service servlet fires off a http request to //hello:8888//SantaClaus?patient=476854.
9. Proxy/Service servlet receives response from //hello:8888//SantaClaus?patient=476854. Parsesand and massages the response. Embellish the response with more stuffs. Encode the whole response as JSON (or encapsulates info as RPC POJO) and sends it as response to GWT client.
10. GWT client request-callback is triggered, and behaves as any GWT client that had sent out a REST or RPC request and got back a response. Interprets the data and displays it on the widgets it had prepared.

**What is the proxy servlet?**

The proxy servlet I described is not the usual http proxy. Rather, it is a normal servlet providing REST or RPC service. I call it a proxy because it is a proxy to allow http clients to access legacy/middleware apps that are not http enabled.

The servlet accepts http requests and transforms them into invocation of legacy application. Frequently, it might involve writing terminal emulator because many legacy apps were written in old VMS, IBM VM, or even Sperry/Unisys where the apps only accepts terminal entry. There are terminal emulation libraries for that.

Fortunately, your service does not need to perform terminal emu, but simply translates one http request into another.

What I recommend is using JAX-RS (RestEasy or Jersey) for the REST listener servlet which listens any http requests that corresponds to the service interface you declare. The listener will spontaneously trigger the interface's implementation. The interface impl will contain the routines to trigger/invoke/dial-into the legacy app and transform its data as a response.

For JAX-RS with GWT, read http://h2g2java.blessedgeek.com/2011/12/gwt-with-jax-rs-aka-rpcrest-part-1.html.

Comment: Any suggestions regarding how to implement this proxy servlet? Actually I work on an Apache server: the old application is based on Wordpress. It make sense to create a service written in PHP instead of a Java servlet, or is more convenient to create a Java servlet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GWT` to go at the `DOM` level.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiDom

Not sure if I really understood your question.